# Pandas: writing series to json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have dataframe

```
      product_type  bank          target  val event_time
0                1    24  target_offline  1.0    2017-04
1                1    10      non_target  1.0    2017-04
10               1     6      non_target  1.0    2017-04
19               1    97      non_target  1.0    2017-05
64               1    10      non_target  1.0    2017-06
106              2    24  target_offline  1.0    2017-04
107              2    10      non_target  1.0    2017-04
116              2     6      non_target  1.0    2017-04
125              2    97      non_target  1.0    2017-05
170              2    10      non_target  1.0    2017-06
212              3    24  target_offline  1.0    2017-04
```

I use

```
d = df.groupby(['product_type', 'bank', 'target'])['event_time', 'val'].apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(x.set_index('event_time')['val'].to_dict())).to_json(nielson_telecom, orient='index')
```

But it returns

```
TypeError: Series.name must be a hashable type
```

I also try to use `DataFrame`, but it returns

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Desire output looks like

```
{'product_type':{
           '6':{
           'target_offline':{
                  '2017-04': 1,
                  '2017-05': 0, ...}}}
```

}

I use

```
    with open('name', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(json.loads(nielson_telecom.getvalue()), f, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Comment: @JohnGalt add to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks overly-complicated. Sure it is not something like this you need?

```
import json

dict_ = {"product_type":{}}
for key,value in df.groupby(['product_type', 'bank', 'target']):
    dict_["product_type"][str(key[1])] = {key[2]:value.set_index("event_time")["val"].to_dict()}

with open("output.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(dict_, indent=4))
    print(json.dumps(dict_, indent=4))
```

Prints and outputs to "output.json":

```
{
    "product_type": {
        "97": {
            "non_target": {
                "2017-05": 1.0
            }
        },
        "6": {
            "non_target": {
                "2017-04": 1.0
            }
        },
        "24": {
            "target_offline": {
                "2017-04": 1.0
            }
        },
        "10": {
            "non_target": {
                "2017-04": 1.0,
                "2017-06": 1.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**update**: if you want to include the different product types:
Not the nicest solution but it works

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

dict_ = defaultdict(dict)

for key,value in df.groupby(['product_type', 'bank', 'target']):
    dict_["product_type{}".format(key[0])][str(key[1])] = {key[2]:value.set_index("event_time")["val"].to_dict()}    

with open("output.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(dict_, indent=4))
    print(json.dumps(dict_, indent=4))
```

Comment: How write that to json file?

Comment: @PetrPetrov Updated to include file output, however I am still not sure this is 100% correct. But hopefully if something is missing someone else can fill in.